# Create new URI from Base URI and Relative Path - slash makes a difference?

Tags: c#, .net, uri, trailing-slash

*Why* does a slash make difference when using [new URI(baseUri, relativePath)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hst1w91(v=vs.110).aspx)?

> This constructor creates a Uri instance by combining the baseUri and the relativeUri ..

And, *how* can can a relative path be appended safely/consistently to a URI?

```
var badBase = new Uri("http://amee/noTrailingSlash");
var goodBase = new Uri("http://amee/trailingSlash/");
var f = "relPath";
new Uri(badBase, f)     // BAD  -> http://amee/relPath
new Uri(goodBase, f)    // GOOD -> http://amee/trailingSlash/relPath
```

The desired output is "good" case, even when the initial URI does not have a trailing slash.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Why does a slash make difference when using new URI(baseUri, relativePath)?

Well, that's what happens on the web normally.

For example, suppose I'm looking at `http://foo.com/some/file1.html` and there's a link to `file2.html` - that link goes to `http://foo.com/some/file2.html`, right? Not `http://foo.com/some/file1.html/file2.html`.

More specifically though, this follows section 5.2.3 of [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).

> 5.2.3.  Merge Paths
>
> The pseudocode above refers to a "merge" routine for merging a
>      relative-path reference with the path of the base URI.  This is
>      accomplished as follows:
>
> - If the base URI has a defined authority component and an empty
>       path, then return a string consisting of "/" concatenated with the
>       reference's path; otherwise,
> - return a string consisting of the reference's path component
>       *appended to all but the last segment of the base URI's path* (i.e.,
>       excluding any characters after the right-most "/" in the base URI
>       path, or excluding the entire base URI path if it does not contain
>       any "/" characters).

Comment: I was just found your [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1558437/2864740) too. Thanks for including the RFC link, as that explicitly answers my "why" question.

Comment: @user2864740: Thanks for adding the appropriate quote :)

Comment: I don't suppose there is an alternate `URI(eitherOrSlash) -> URI(withSlash)` without going the `URI->String->URI route`?

Comment: @user2864740: Not that I'm aware of, I'm afraid :(

Answer (score 15):

I've been playing around with the Uri constructor with the overload `new Uri(baseUri, relativePath)`.  Perhaps others may find the results useful.  Here's the output from the test application I wrote:

```
A) Base Address is domain only
==============================

NO trailing slash on base address, NO leading slash on relative path:
http://foo.com   +  relative1/relative2 :
    http://foo.com/relative1/relative2

NO trailing slash on base address, relative path HAS leading slash:
http://foo.com   +  /relative1/relative2 :
    http://foo.com/relative1/relative2

Base address HAS trailing slash, NO leading slash on relative path:
http://foo.com/   +  relative1/relative2 :
    http://foo.com/relative1/relative2

Base address HAS trailing slash, relative path HAS leading slash:
http://foo.com/   +  /relative1/relative2 :
    http://foo.com/relative1/relative2

B) Base Address includes path
=============================

NO trailing slash on base address, NO leading slash on relative path:
http://foo.com/base1/base2   +  relative1/relative2 :
    http://foo.com/base1/relative1/relative2 
    (removed base2 segment)

NO trailing slash on base address, relative path HAS leading slash:
http://foo.com/base1/base2   +  /relative1/relative2 :
    http://foo.com/relative1/relative2
    (removed base1 and base2 segments)

Base address HAS trailing slash, NO leading slash on relative path:
http://foo.com/base1/base2/   +  relative1/relative2 :
    http://foo.com/base1/base2/relative1/relative2
    (has all segments)

Base address HAS trailing slash, relative path HAS leading slash:
http://foo.com/base1/base2/   +  /relative1/relative2 :
    http://foo.com/relative1/relative2
    (removed base1 and base2 segments)
```

Comment: I would never have guessed the behaviour of `new Uri()` with a base address that has a path. This answer saved me a lot of hair.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same, and arrived at the following solution:

```
var badBase = new Uri("http://amee/noTrailingSlash");
var goodBase = new Uri("http://amee/trailingSlash/");
var f = "relPath";
string badBaseUrl = Path.Combine(badBase,f);
string goodBaseUrl = Path.Combine(goodBase,f);
new Uri(badBaseUrl);  //----> (http://amee/trailingSlash/relPath)
new Uri(goodBaseUrl); //---> (http://amee/trailingSlash/relPath)
```